# What should the dimensions be for a "coming soon" page?

Tags: website-design, dimensions

Are there are standard dimensions for a coming soon page?

I tried to google it and search for an answer on here but I didn't find any satisfactory answers. I mostly saw the dimensions recommended to be 1000x700px so that's what I'm currently using, but still there's space left on each side. Or am I doing it wrong?

Thanks in Advance :-)

Comment: Why make dimensions for a page at all?

Comment: This would depend *entirely* on the content. If it's just a logo and 1 or 2 lines of text.... it doesn't much matter.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, creating a "coming soon" page might not be a good idea at all. We have [a discussion](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/39459/23061) about whether or not they are helpful which I hope you read and consider the arguments.

If you still think that you should create a "coming soon" page, then the best practice would not be to design for one particular set of dimensions, but rather to design *responsively*, meaning it should look good on all screen sizes.

If you're new to responsive design, I wrote an [intro to responsive web design](http://zachsaucier.com/blog/blog/2014/08/11/responsive-design-primer/) that describes how to design responsively in more detail than I can go into in this answer. If you have questions or comments I'd love to hear them. You might also be able to learn some things by reading through questions that have the [responsive-design](/questions/tagged/responsive-design) tag.

With a "coming soon" page, designing responsively should be quite simple because there is likely not much content at all.

Answer (score 1):

> Are there are standard dimensions for a coming soon page?

No.